# Django how many fields can i put unique in a model?

Tags: django, django-models

I can put two fields unique True?

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    age = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Comment: `last_name` should probably not be unique? Many students may share the same last name. There is no limit although you may run into performance issue inserting data if you have a lot of indexes on a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have as many unique as you need. But if you want no two students to have the same name, you'll want to use `unique_together`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'last_name'),)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    age = models.BigIntegerField()
```

This will allow two people to have the same first name, or same last name.. but not both.  Probably STILL not a good idea, because sometimes people do have identical names.. but if you want that behavior, this is how you would do it.

Comment: I understand, but if I use 2 unique true fields, can I have problems with the database? How many unique fields can I use in a model?

Comment: There is no limit that you have to worry about.  Sure, every time you create a unique constraint on a column (field), the database will create an index on that column.  That is something the database engine (hopefully you are using postgres) does automatically and you don't have to worry about it.  But of course that will take up a little space on disk... so there IS some limit.  But the limit is huge and you will not reach it in any normal application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll encounter problems if you have someone with a different `name` and identical `last_name` as another model object and vice versa. Depends on your use case though.

Answer (score 0):

You can put two or more uniques constraints in but they act separately in your case. In your example the constraint limit for only have one student per name or last name, in other words, the system not allow to have two students with the same name or last name.

I think you're trying to that two students don't have exactly the same name **and** last name, the important key is **and**.

Two alternatives for achieve that:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'last_name'),)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    age = models.BigIntegerField()
```

or

```py
class Student(models.Model):
   class Meta:
        constraints = (
             models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('name', 'last_name'), name='unique_student_constraint'),  
         )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    age = models.BigIntegerField()
```

The second alternative add  some extra parameters which may be helpful in others cases. [More information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint)